# Webkit reflection mask in Android Chrome

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

**Desktop computer Chrome**

[image: desktop]

With Chrome on a desktop computer, I can get an image reflection with:

```
img {  
 -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 -webkit-gradient(
  linear, 
  left top, 
  left bottom, 
  from(transparent), 
  color-stop(.7, transparent), 
  to(white)
 );  
}
```

**Android Chrome**

[image: android]

When tested on Android's Chrome, the mask is not really a mask. It becomes a plain overlay gradient. How do I turn it into a true mask? On my real website, I have a patterned background, so a plain overlay gradient wouldn't be able to gradually reveal the background.

Comment: I can't help you with the actual CSS, but Android doesn't run Chrome as its browser.

Comment: I know it's not exactly Chrome. It's some mobile variant of Chrome. It uses Webkit rendering.

Comment: @JoJo: No, it is not "some mobile variant of Chrome", any more than Safari is an "Apple variant of Chrome". The standard Android browser is based on WebKit and otherwise has little similarity to Chrome. That being said, you might investigate techniques that work on iOS, as both iOS and Android will be working off of the mobile edition of WebKit, and so it may be you can find a solution that way.

Answer (score 1):

The Android browser doesn't support webkit gradients as masks on box-reflects. However, you can use PNG masks, and to avoid an extra HTTP request, encode them as Base64 for use in a Data URI:

```
img {
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0 
  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAyCAYAAACUEBHwAAAAIklEQVQ4jWP8//8/AzpgwhAZFRwVHBUctIIsDAwMXFQWBAAW4QORoT0UUQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

You can generate a PNG gradient using tools like http://www.display-inline.fr/projects/css-gradient/ and convert it to Base64 with something like http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/